# Do all script users need Powershell installed?

Tags: powershell

Looking to use Powershell for writing some scripts. The concern is, do all users of the script need Powershell installed on their computer in order to have the script execute properly? Is the behavior different for Windows 7 vs. XP vs. 2k etc? I understand powershell is included in 8, so that's not a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell is also included in Windows 7. PowerShell might be included in XP not sure on that. I'm pretty sure 2k does not have PowerShell. Yes, if you want to run a PowerShell script you will need to have PowerShell installed. Just like you would need Python installed if you want to run a Python script.

I know that Win 7 comes with PS version 2.0 by default. Not sure on XP. The current version is PS is 3.0 it comes with the [Windows Management Framework (WMF) 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595).

During December 2012 Microsoft had the WMF 3.0 deployed as an update but recalled it a couple of weeks later because there was some [compatibly errors with other stuff](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/12/20/windows-management-framework-3-0-compatibility-update.aspx).

I'm using PS 3.0 and updating all my computers to PS 3.0. [PS add new stuff that I want to learn.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857339.aspx)

Comment: Don't forget to change the Execution Policy to run scripts.

Comment: Or, alternately, sign your scripts with a certificate the clients will trust.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know. Also, found a topic on here that talked about install and setup including on Execution Policy & another on Signing.  Thanks Again!

Comment: If installation is a hurdle, [Portable Powershell](http://site.shelltools.net/applications/portable_powershell) might be worth a look